# I have a problem comparing two Japanese strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Even though two Japanese strings seem identical, why don't they give correct results when compared in JavaScript?

```
const str1 : string="廣瀬和廣"
const str2 : string="廣瀨和廣"
if(str1 === str2){
  console.log('true')
} else {
  console.log('false')
}
```

But result is false

```
false
```

Does anyone know why please help me

Comment: Hint: 瀬 is not 瀨. It's more obvious if you increase your font size.

Comment: Tip: `console.log(x == y)` is way shorter than all this `if` stuff.

Answer (score 5):

They're different strings, even if they look the similar.

```js
encodeURIComponent("廣瀬和廣") -> '%E5%BB%A3%E7%80%AC%E5%92%8C%E5%BB%A3'
encodeURIComponent("廣瀨和廣") -> '%E5%BB%A3%E7%80%A8%E5%92%8C%E5%BB%A3'
                      ^                            ^
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @tadman see updated answer